# how to know if a property from PropertInfo (reflection) Is an Array

Tags: arrays, vb.net, class, reflection

i got a class like that :

```
<Serializable()> Public Class SACCVar


Private _Code_Produit As String
Private _Voie_Ana_Name(6) As String

Public Property Voie_Ana_Name(index As Integer) As String
    Get
        Return _Voie_Ana_Name(index)
    End Get
    Set(value As String)

        _Voie_Ana_Name(index) = value
    End Set
End Property
 Public Property Code_Produit As String
        Get
            Return _Code_Produit
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
             _Code_Produit = value
         End Set
    End Property
    End Class
```

then i want to loop through the class property using this :

```
dim saccdata as SACCVar
Dim VarType As Type = GetType(SACCVar)
Dim properties As PropertyInfo() = VarType.GetProperties()

 For Each proper As PropertyInfo In properties

    proper.GetValue(SaccData, {0})

 next
```

BUT with the getvalue if i want to get code_produit i have to set *nothing* in place of {0} because it's not an array.

So my question is how do i detect that **proper** is an array or not?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to retrieve the type of the property with the [PropertyInfo.PropertyType Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.propertytype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
Then you can use the [Type.IsArray Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isarray%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to check if the type is an array.

```
For Each proper As PropertyInfo In properties
   If proper.PropertyType.IsArray Then
      [...]
   End If
next
```

Comment: thank you but unfortunately i ever tested that but it always returning me false... any idea what i am missing?

Comment: Ok i think i see the probleme . My private variable is an array BUT my property isn't it's just a property with an index. An idée on how to test if it got an index. I am searching in that way...

Comment: You can test for an indexed property with the [PropertyInfo.GetIndexParameters Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getindexparameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: sorry i didn't see your answer. That's right i didn't see this method... Thank you